# Conversion from factor to numeric in R

Tags: r

Take a factor in R, let's say:

```
fac <- factor(c(2,3,4))
```

If I convert it to a numeric like so (edited, I originally posted the hashed out line):

```
#fac |> as.character(as.numeric())
fac |> as.numeric(as.character())
```

I get the numeric vector: c(1,2,3), which is of course wrong.

However this isn't the equivalent of either:

```
fac |> as.numeric() |> as.character()
```

which gives c("1","2","3"), or:

```
fac |> as.character() |> as.numeric()
```

which would give c(2,3,4)

Any help with what's going on?

Comment: You're already familiar with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418192/190277 , right? When I run `fac |> as.character(as.numeric())` I get `c("2", "3", "4")` (with R-devel/4.4.0). In any case a nested function call on the RHS of a pipe seems weird/sketchy?

Comment: Yes I knew that would convert wrong if I simply converted to a numeric. I'm just not sure why I get a numeric vector c(1,2,3). I've checked and it's still happening. I'm on R 4.2.1, so a bit out of date.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [R NEWS file](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/master/doc/NEWS.Rd) that would suggest a relevant change to the behaviour of `|>`. Can you try tracing (as in my answer) and post your results?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm wasting everyone's time. I was doing: fac |> as.numeric(as.character()), which gives me c(1,2,3)

Comment: Yup ...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually want to know what `fac |> as.character(as.numeric())` does (as opposed to "how should I convert a factor to its numerical equivalent?", which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418192/190277)), try the following:

```r
> trace("as.character")
> trace("as.numeric")
> fac |> as.character(as.numeric())
trace: as.character(fac, as.numeric())
trace: as.numeric()
[1] "2" "3" "4"
```

i.e., here's what's happening:

- call `as.character()` with *first argument* `fac` and *second argument* `as.numeric()`
- `as.numeric()` returns `numeric(0)` (i.e., an empty numeric vector)
- looking at `?as.character`, it takes a `...` argument which can be used to pass optional arguments to the methods for converting a particular type. *As far as I can tell this is simply ignored in the case of the `as.character.factor` method ...*
- so we end up calling the equivalent of `as.character(fac)` → the result is `c("2", "3", "4")`

In contrast, `fac |> as.numeric(as.character())` (**nesting in the opposite order** from what was originally written in the question) evaluates `as.character()` (→ empty character vector) and includes it as the second argument to `as.numeric()`, which is again ignored, so the result is equivalent to `as.numeric(fac)` (which is `c(1, 2, 3)` as explained in various places ...)

For what it's worth, the magrittr/tidyverse pipe (`%>%`) gives the same results (for me).

R 4.4.0 (devel) on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Try `type.convert`

```
> type.convert(fac, as.is = TRUE)
[1] 2 3 4
```

or `levels`

```
> as.numeric(levels(fac))[fac]
[1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: Never seen `type.convert` this way, so obvious +1! And about 10% faster than second option.

Answer (score 1):

The factor `fac` has levels `"2"`, `"3"`, and `"4"`, which are internally represented as `1`, `2` and `3`.

So the following makes perfect sense:

```r
fac <- factor(c(2,3,4))

as.numeric(fac)
#> [1] 1 2 3
as.character(fac)
#> [1] "2" "3" "4"
as.numeric(as.character(fac))
#> [1] 2 3 4
as.character(as.numeric(fac))
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"

f1 <- function(x) {
  as.character(as.numeric(x))
}

fac |> as.character(as.numeric())
#> [1] "2" "3" "4"

f1(fac)
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I am not sure that `fac |> as.character(as.numeric())` is particularly clear. I don't seem to get the same answer (see above).

Comment: Agreed it's not clear - very janky. I just can't figure out why it's giving me the numeric. I've changed it now to work, but I didn't catch it in my analysis for a while. On R 4.2.1 so maybe it's a bug that was fixed?

Comment: On `fac |> as.character(as.numeric())` see the answer from @ben-bolker.